# Sum of an array while ignoring one minimum and one maximum

Tags: python, list

I have a program that finds the highest and lowest values in an array, excludes them, then sums up the rest of the numbers in that array. It works with most random inputs, except for cases when there are duplicates of the highest or the lowest number in that array

```
def sum_array(arr):
    if arr is None:
        return 0
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return 0
    return sum([i for i in arr if i != max(arr) and i != min(arr)])
```

In which case if I `print(sum_array([6, 0, 1, 10, 10]))`, it only returns 7 instead of 17.

It excluded the highest number entirely.

How do I make the program recognize that there are duplicates and take just one of them for the sum so, in this case, it can return 17?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Can there be more than two of the min or max values? ... `[10,0,6,1,0,10,10]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just subtract the `min` and `max` from the overall `sum`, so it only counts as one occurrence:

```
a = [6, 0, 1, 10, 10]

sum(a) - max(a) - min(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
return sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1])
```

Just sort the array and sum every number except the first and the last.

Comment: Meh. For lists this small it's certainly fine. If you need to process massive lists, your approach is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for. This is O(n) Time Complexity and O(1) Space Complexity.

```
def sum_array(arr):
    if arr is None or len(arr) < 2:
        return 0
    maximum = max(arr)
    minimum = min(arr)
    return sum(arr) - maximum - minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list into set i. e set(arr) then you will get the unique elements. Now you can igmore max and minimum and get some of all elements. Do let me know if you need code.

Comment: The set will remove duplicates of the *middle* values also. Spec is not to count duplicate mins/maxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [6, 0, 1, 10, 10]

def my_sum(arr = list()):
    arr.sort()
    c = Counter(arr)
    cur_min = arr[0]
    cur_max = arr[-1]

    my_sum = sum(arr) - cur_min * (c.get(cur_min)- 1) - cur_max * (c.get(cur_max) - 1)
    return my_sum


### in case of large arrays avoiding the sort: 
def my_sum2(arr = list()):
    cur_min = arr[0]
    cur_max = arr[0]
    c = Counter()
    res = 0
    for x in arr:
        cur_min = min(cur_min, x)
        cur_max = max(cur_max, x)
        c[x] += 1
        res += x

    res = res - cur_min * (c.get(cur_min) - 1) - cur_max * (c.get(cur_max) - 1)
    return res


print(my_sum(arr))
print(my_sum2(arr))
```

It won't ignore duplicates between cur_min and cur_max.

Answer (score -1):

This works. Remove maximum and minimum values from the list and compute sum

```
a = [6, 0, 1, 10, 10]
maximum = max(a)
minimum = min(a)
a = list(filter((maximum).__ne__, a))
a = list(filter((minimum).__ne__, a))

print(sum(a)+maximum+minimum)
```

if you do not want to modify input list, then use `a_copy = a.copy()` and use `a_copy` in place of `a`

Comment: *One* minimum and *one* maximum should be removed; instead you're removing *all* minimums and *all* maximums and add *one* of each back in. Not the same algorithm at all.

Comment: Taking only one of minimum and maximum values into consideration. Rest of the duplicates must be removed

Comment: If there is only one min/max to begin with, your code is removing it but then adding it back it…

Comment: List values are not of concern. Sum is what matters here i guess

Comment: Right, so the expected result for `a = [6, 0, 1, 10]` should be `7`, right…? Your code doesn't produce `7`.

Comment: Answer for `[6,0,1,10]` must be `17` i guess. Since there are no duplicates, sum would be `sum(a)`

Comment: *"[..] finds the highest and lowest values in an array, excludes them, then sums up the rest of the numbers in that array. It works with most random inputs, except for cases when there's duplicates of the highest or the lowest number [..]"* — Min/max should *always* be excluded, not only when there's a duplicate.

Comment: Totally overlooked that statement. You're right then.